# Regex: Finding URLs in background-image CSS, having trouble

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

Here's my regex code:

```
preg_match_all('/background[-image]*:[\s]*url\(["|\']+(.*)["|\']+\)/', $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

It looks for CSS that looks like this:

```
background:url('../blah.jpg');
```

My problem I'm having is some CSS I scrape looks like this:

```
background:transparent url('../blah.jpg');
background:transparent no-repeat url('../blah.jpg');
```

I'm no expert when it comes to regex, so I'm wondering how I can tell it to skip anything after the colon and before URL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ths should catch all the images unless I skipped anything.

```
preg_match_all('~\bbackground(-image)?\s*:(.*?)\(\s*(\'|")?(?<image>.*?)\3?\s*\)~i',$str,$matches);
$images = $matches['image'];
print_r($images);
```

Comment: BTW, `<image>` adds the matched string to `$matches['image']`? I didn't know that! Good one!!

Comment: Yep. $matches normally catches all the parenthesized values and the whole match but once you know where exactly you want to get regardless of where it is in your regex you can use labels. It's much more practical.

Comment: This is matching non-URLs for me.  Specifically, gradients; had to add  `url` before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/background[-image]*:.*[\s]*url\(["|\']+(.*)["|\']+\)/', $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: How do you check if it has no double or single quote? Can't quit seem how to pass "nothing" lol as an options

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/background(-image)??\s*?:.*?url\(["|\']??(.+)["|\']??\)/', $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

I replaced `:[\s]*` with `:.*?` which should do the trick - means that it will match any character, the previous regex matched only spaces after `:`

Comment: `[-image]*` means `Zero or more of the characters [-aegim]`. `(-image)?` would be better.